# Need help making a box on my main page the same size as the other boxes (when zooming)

Tags: html, css

This is a screen shot of what's going on and what i would like to happen:

This is for the index.php page of rankingclimber.com (you'll go to it when you go to the domain)

http://www.screencast.com/users/rockstarvisible/folders/Jing/media/ba62a835-9299-46b1-950e-04b631e6cdc2

you can see the code for the file at rankingclimber.com/index.php

What do I change in my style sheet? Or do I just change the html in the index.php page?

the css file is located at rankingclimber.com/css/style.css

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to modify your style sheet like I suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at your page and it seems that the problem is due to line #4 in the last box (How high will my rankings go up by?). It wraps to a second line when zoomed in.  This causes the last box be be taller.

You can't set the height of the 3 boxes to 100%, as WEBProject suggested, because you are floating them and you can't just specify a height on the outer container since the boxes are comprised of several background images.  The easiest solution, aside from changing the text to something shorter, is to make the boxes a little taller to accommodate the extra line in the last box.

Comment: Hey Nimrod. Thanks for the help. What do I specifically change in the style sheet (in the /** Topblocks **/ part)? The style sheet is located at http://www.rankingclimber.com/css/style.css.

Comment: Line 46 in your stylesheet. Set a height on class b_tp, like 175px.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap those three boxes in a div, give him some min-height (so the all boxes starts with the same height) - then give those boxes - height:100%; and they will al strech to the wrapper divs height. whenever one of the boxes gets bigger, the main div will also gain height, and because of the 100% height, they will all be on the same size.

Hope i helped.